# Optimization code for checking if a list contains any element ID of another list

Tags: c#, performance, .net, linq, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
var sessionsWithError = SessionsFilteredByDate
    .Where(i => i.TrackerId > 0 && i.StatusId == 0)
    .Select(i => i.SessionId);
var sessionsWithErrorFixed = BusinessClient.Instance.Tracker
    .GetAllTrackerAttempts()
    .Select(i => i.SessionId);
var sessionsWithErrorIntersection = sessionsWithError.Intersect(sessionsWithErrorFixed);
var sessionsWithErrorsNotFixed = sessionsWithError.Except(sessionsWithErrorIntersection);
```

Then I have to create a `IEnumerable` where I put all the `SessionsFilteredByDate` where the `sessionID` is included in `sessionsWithErrorsNotFixed`, but this operation, since I am using the `Any` operator, it's slow, apparently \$O(m*n)\$.

How can I achieve this operation with a lower complexity?

```
SessionsFilteredByDateAndErrors = SessionsFilteredByDate
    .Where(i => sessionsWithErrorsNotFixed.Any(y => y == i.SessionId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the values into a `HashSet<T>` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)) as the lookup for that is constant O(1).

```
var sessionsWithErrorSet = new HashSet<int>(
    SessionsFilteredByDate.Where(i => i.TrackerId > 0 && i.StatusId == 0).Select(i => i.SessionId));

var sessionsWithErrorFixedSet = new HashSet<int>(
    BusinessClient.Instance.Tracker.GetAllTrackerAttempts().Select(i => i.SessionId));

var sessionsWithErrorIntersection = sessionsWithError.IntersectWith(sessionsWithErrorFixed);
var sessionsWithErrorsNotFixed = sessionsWithError.ExceptWith(sessionsWithErrorIntersection);
```